# Opendir works only with absolute path

Tags: php, path, warnings, opendir

When using following code:

```
if ($handle = opendir('../flat')) {

}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: opendir(../flat) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in D:\Inetpub\webs\mysite\newSite\lib\flat.php on line 1
```

Using

```
dirname(__FILE__);
```

I can see the correct path of my PHP script:

```
D:\Inetpub\webs\mysite\newSite\lib
```

Using absolute path `opendir` works good:

```
if ($handle = opendir('D:\Inetpub\webs\mysite\newSite\flat')) {

}
```

What could be the problem? Can someone help me?

Comment: Use a path explicitly relative to the script directory:  `dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '../flat'`.

Answer (score -2):

PHP's open dir functions don't work with URLs, unless they're full and absolute. Your relative path will not work with open dir unless it is a file directory or absolute path like http://www.example.com/blah/blah..

According to the PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php):

a) path supports the ftp:// URL wrapper.

b) path can also be any URL which supports directory listing, however only the file:// URL wrapper supports this in PHP 4